# Showing possible property values in custom webcontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a custom control that print the current date into the page.
The control has a Format property for setting witch DateTime property to be printed. (Date, Day, Year etc...)

```
<TSC:DateTimeWriter runat="server" Format="Year" />
```

But what i want is when i type :

> Format="

I want to show a list of all the possible values(Using Visual Studio).

The cs code:

```
public class DateTimeWriter : Control
{
    public string Format { get; set; }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write(writeDateTime());
    }

    private string writeDateTime()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        switch (Format)
        {
            case "Year":
                return now.Year.ToString();
            case "Day":
                return now.Day.ToString();
            etc...
            default:
                return now.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the Format property an enum instead of a string, VS will be able to display a list of supported formats. E.g.:

```
public enum DateTimeFormat
{
    Year,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an enumerated Type

namespace YourNameSpace

{

```
[Serializable()]

public enum DateFormat

{

    Date,

    Day,

    Year

}
```

}

then add a property to your control:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Date Format
    /// </summary>
    public DateFormat DateFormat
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["DateFormat"] == null || ViewState["DateFormat"].ToString().Trim() == String.Empty)
            {
                return DateFormat.Date;  //Default
            }
            return (DateFormat)ViewState["DateFormat"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["DateFormat"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The Enum part is correct. but if i use the control several placec within a page the ViewState stuff will not work. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: The ViewState will be tied to the instance of the WebControl, so you can have multiple controls on one page and they wont conflict.